# How to get mp3 url for a YouTube link using YouTube-dl python api?

Tags: python, api, youtube-api, httprequest

I need an mp3 url. So that I can use that URL to open it in vlc directly so that vlc could just play as streaming. I found the following code on stackoverflow. Is there any change I can make in it to get mp3 url.

I am making [pyMusicFs](https://github.com/Rushikesh005/pyMusicFs)

```
import youtube_dl

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})
# Add all the available extractors
ydl.add_default_info_extractors()

result = ydl.extract_info('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'
,   download=False # We just want to extract the info
  )

 if 'entries' in result:
  # Can be a playlist or a list of videos
  Video = result ['entries'] [0]
 else:
  # Just a video
 video = result

 print(video)
 video_url = video['url']
 print(video_url)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `extract_info` method will return all formats available, but whether or not it will include an MP3 depends on YouTube. I don't think I ever saw a video with an MP3 link available, but most include a [M4A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4A) version (which is audio-only).

**Update**: using your sample code, you could get the m4a audio with:

```
for format in video['formats']:
  if format['ext'] == 'm4a':
    audio_url = format['url']
```

PS: you must have a recent version of VLC to be able to play it.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: `audio_url = [format['url'] for format in video['formats'] if format['ext'] == 'm4a']`